# SSL Handshake Failure Alert for JDK7

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, liferay-6.2

I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE GA2 Framework which is running on JDK7.
While calling Discourse Forum API using Apache httpclient it throws exception: **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**.

I think this is because*JDK7 doesn’t implement any **GCM** cipher suite.

And Discourse Forum is configured with SSL Protocol: **TLSv1.2** and Strong Cipher Suites: **TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384**

How to resolve this issue? Or is there any other way to call Discourse API from Java platform.

Thanks,

Saurabh Khandelwal

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Before you fix this problem, you *really* need to [upgrade and patch](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/security-patches-for-liferay-portal-6-2-7-0-and-7-1).

Which also *might* bring you closer to a solution: The compatibility matrix for Liferay EE 6.2 lists Java 8 as compatible - I'm not sure when this came in, but there's a good chance that the later GA versions in CE are also compatible. With that, you should have a newer set of TLS algorithms.

Otherwise you'd have to ask the Discourse admins to enable some algorithm that's compatible with your Java version.

(Disclaimer: I've not checked available algorithms in Java7, but it sounds like an unsupported algorithm is indeed a plausible root cause)

Did I mention that you *really* should update *urgently*?